# Flatten array of nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, nested

I have an array of nested hashes that looks something like this:

```
[{"month"=>1,
  "percentiles"=>{"25"=>768.06, "50"=>1868.5, "75"=>3043.79, "90"=>4161.6},
  "total_revenue"=>1308620.0,
  "year"=>2017},
 {"month"=>2,
  "percentiles"=>{"25"=>922.63, "50"=>2074.31, "75"=>3048.87, "90"=>4018.6},
  "total_revenue"=>1105860.0,
  "year"=>2017}]
```

That I would like to flatten into this:

```
[{"month"=>1,
      "25"=>768.06, "50"=>1868.5, "75"=>3043.79, "90"=>4161.6,
      "total_revenue"=>1308620.0,
      "year"=>2017},
     {"month"=>2,
      "25"=>922.63, "50"=>2074.31, "75"=>3048.87, "90"=>4018.6,
      "total_revenue"=>1105860.0,
      "year"=>2017}]
```

I have been looking and testing different methods with no luck. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? The end goal is to mass update/insert these into a database, so if there is a better way to accomplish that, I would like to see a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying the array in-place then you could say:

```
array.each { |h| h.merge!(h.delete('percentiles')) }
```

If you're not sure that all the hashes have `'percentiles'` keys then you could say:

```
# Explicitly check
array.each { |h| h.merge!(h.delete('percentiles')) if(h.has_key?('percentiles')) }
# Convert possible `nil`s to `{ }`
array.each { |h| h.merge!(h.delete('percentiles').to_h) }
# Filter before merging
array.select { |h| h.has_key?('percentiles') }.each { |h| h.merge!(h.delete('percentiles')) }
```

If you want to flatten all hash values then you can do things like this:

```
array.each do |h|
  h.keys.each do |k|
    if(h[k].is_a?(Hash))
      h.merge!(h.delete(k))
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't want to modify the hashes inside the array then variations on:

```
flat = array.map(&:dup).each { |h| h.merge!(h.delete('percentiles')) }

flat = array.map do |e|
  e.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
    if(v.is_a?(Hash))
      h.merge!(v)
    else
      h[k] = v
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I had finally figured out a way to do it but it was taking my five lines. I ultimately settled with this which also allows me to transform the keys from numbers to strings (they are defined on key_map:  `@revenue_by_month.each { |h| h.merge!(h.delete('percentiles').transform_keys {|k| @key_map[k]}) }`